# Why isn't my css getting minified?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, system.web.optimization

I'm not clear what I'm missing here. As far as I can tell I've [followed the instruction here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification). But my css bundle is still not getting minified.

Here's my `RegisterBundles` code:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.UseCdn = true;
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/otherjquery").Include(
            "~/App_Themes/Travel2/Script/jquery-ui.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));

   Bundle availabiltyResult = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css/availabiltyResult").Include(
                "~/CSS/Travel2/Air.css",
                "~/CSS/Travel2/Air/AvailabiltyResults.css"
                );
    availabiltyResult.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
    bundles.Add(availabiltyResult);
}
```

I've disabled debugging in my web.config by removing the `<compilation debug="true">`. I can see the js getting bundled and minified:

[image]

but the css is getting bundled but not minified:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you link to your TFS or Git Repo, so we can see the full picture?

Comment: You are looking at a Firebug view - Firebug reformats the CSS to be more readable. View the source in a text editor.

Comment: Cr*p, your right @Kami. Looking at it using fiddler I can see it is minified. #Fail

Comment: @Liam At least it's not an actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the file **was** getting minified but that [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) was re-parsing the code so it looked like it wasn't. Looking at it using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) I can see that the css is (in fact) getting minified:

[image]

Kudos to @Kimi for the spotting it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to **build** your code as **Release**.

Comment: No I don't. The web.config does this not the debug variable.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the config. The VS does the minifying at building the solution - therefore you have to set Release build and start/rebuild the project.Next time read your answer, before you shoot from hip! Just think about: while you do debugging, minifying would be unconvenient, so that's why minifying occours only when you do a Release build. At least this works for JS.

Comment: No, that's wrong. I am running it right now in DEBUG and the minification is happening. The `<compilation debug="true">` actually turns it on or off. You sure you don't have you release config set to remove this setting from the web.config?

Comment: Actually, by default the web.config has `compilation debug="true"` turned off.  Which directly impacts the minification process.  So as long as that is enabled, it doesn't need to be in *release*.  Rick Anderson has a really stellar article about the whole process here. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification